# How to append data from XLSX to XLSX in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, com, append, xlsx

I'm trying to build a script with the Powershell Excel COM object which reads an XLSX file and looks at the columns. If it matches the columns of the target XLSX file I want it to append the data to the target. How should I start?

I already managed to do it with TXT files (turning it to objects and appending to XLSX) and now I'm trying to do the same with XLSX.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would't really recommend working with Excel through COM Objects when [ImportExcel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) exists, I've used this module for a couple of years now, and its simply awesome. I'm leaving an example of how can you do what you want with this module:

```
Import-Excel .\Object2.xlsx | Export-Excel .\Object1.xlsx -Append
```

This only appends data from the same column names or "properties" so no need to check.

Hope it helps, and thanks to [dfinke](https://github.com/dfinke) for creating this awesome module.